# jquery webcam not working in chrome 35

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-webcam-plugin, webcam-capture

I am trying to access webcam from jquery webcam API. The sample given below works fine in IE9, Firefox, but unfortunately does not work in Chrome v35. It shows the webcam activated but when I click the "Take Picture" button, it gives me a javascript error saying that **webcam.capture** is undefined. In the code below, the **webcam** object does not have any function called **capture()** in chrome; but its found for Firefox and IE9.

Please help me out!!

**Index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.webcam.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<p id="status" style="height:22px; color:#c00;font-weight:bold;"></p>

<div id="webcam" style="width:350px;float: left;"">

<a href="javascript:webcam.capture();changeFilter();void(0);">Take a picture instantly</a>

</div>

<p style="width:350px; float: left;"><canvas id="canvas" height="240" width="320" style="float: left;""></canvas></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
var pos = 0;
var ctx = null;
var cam = null;
var image = null;

var filter_on = false;
var filter_id = 0;

function changeFilter() {
    if (filter_on) {
        filter_id = (filter_id + 1) & 7;
    }
}

function toggleFilter(obj) {
    if (filter_on =!filter_on) {
        obj.parentNode.style.borderColor = "#c00";
    } else {
        obj.parentNode.style.borderColor = "#333";
    }
}

jQuery("#webcam").webcam({

    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    mode: "callback",
    swffile: "http://www.xarg.org/download/jscam_canvas_only.swf",

    onTick: function(remain) {

        if (0 == remain) {
            jQuery("#status").text("Cheese!");
        } else {
            jQuery("#status").text(remain + " seconds remaining...");
        }
    },

    onSave: function(data) {

        var col = data.split(";");
        var img = image;

        for(var i = 0; i < 320; i++) {
            var tmp = parseInt(col[i]);
            img.data[pos + 0] = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
            img.data[pos + 1] = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
            img.data[pos + 2] = tmp & 0xff;
            img.data[pos + 3] = 0xff;
            pos+= 4;
        }

        if (pos >= 0x4B000) {
            ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
            pos = 0;
        }
    },

    onCapture: function () {
        webcam.save();

        jQuery("#flash").css("display", "block");
        jQuery("#flash").fadeOut(100, function () {
            jQuery("#flash").css("opacity", 1);
        });
    },

    debug: function (type, string) {
        jQuery("#status").html(type + ": " + string);
    },

    onLoad: function () {

        var cams = webcam.getCameraList();
        for(var i in cams) {
            jQuery("#cams").append("<li>" + cams[i] + "</li>");
        }
    }
});

function getPageSize() {

    var xScroll, yScroll;

    if (window.innerHeight && window.scrollMaxY) {
        xScroll = window.innerWidth + window.scrollMaxX;
        yScroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollMaxY;
    } else if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight){ // all but Explorer Mac
        xScroll = document.body.scrollWidth;
        yScroll = document.body.scrollHeight;
    } else { // Explorer Mac...would also work in Explorer 6 Strict, Mozilla and Safari
        xScroll = document.body.offsetWidth;
        yScroll = document.body.offsetHeight;
    }

    var windowWidth, windowHeight;

    if (self.innerHeight) { // all except Explorer
        if(document.documentElement.clientWidth){
            windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        } else {
            windowWidth = self.innerWidth;
        }
        windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) { // Explorer 6 Strict Mode
        windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if (document.body) { // other Explorers
        windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }

    // for small pages with total height less then height of the viewport
    if(yScroll < windowHeight){
        pageHeight = windowHeight;
    } else {
        pageHeight = yScroll;
    }

    // for small pages with total width less then width of the viewport
    if(xScroll < windowWidth){
        pageWidth = xScroll;
    } else {
        pageWidth = windowWidth;
    }

    return [pageWidth, pageHeight];
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    jQuery("body").append("<div id=\"flash\"></div>");

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    if (canvas.getContext) {
        ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 240);

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "logo.gif";
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 129, 89);
        }
        image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 320, 240);
    }

    var pageSize = getPageSize();
    jQuery("#flash").css({ height: pageSize[1] + "px" });

}, false);

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {

    var pageSize = getPageSize();
    jQuery("#flash").css({ height: pageSize[1] + "px" });

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. I was initially trying to run the code from a folder location on my system. But when I deployed the same code to a local web application running on tomcat (http://<>/webcam/webcam.html), it started working in chrome!! I was anyhow going to deploy the code tomorrow on a remote server but had no idea that the webcam APIs would be inaccessible from the system if the application is not running on a server. Quite strange, but this saved me!!